# How do you overrite css for rel icon?

Tags: html, css

There is this icon in the index.html page and it is taking its styles from some css file that I cannot locate. I like to override the sytles with inline css and disable hovering on the image.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/fav32.png">
```

can I do something like this? I tried this but did not work?

```
<link rel="icon" style="width:40px !important; height:40px !important, background-color: white !important;hover: disabled !important;" type="image/png" href="img/fav32.png">
```

Comment: well, `hover` isn't a valid `CSS` property for starters..You'll need to put a `CSS` class together to target a hover.

Comment: `<link>` is a `<head>` element, which you can't style with CSS. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @ralph.m, there is an image when I hovered on it, there is a text, I need to disable showing up the text when I hover over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what a `rel="icon"` link tag does. It is called a ["favicon"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) This puts an image into the browser's tab area (and on some browsers into the address bar) but the browsers give you no control over this other than specifying the image (and in some modern browsers, the ability to specify multiple sized images).

Any text that appears on hover is a browser-specific message that is uncontrollable by the site/developer.